# apt-get update debian error

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

I tried setting up Debian 7 (32 bit) on my vps. When I run apt-get update on the shell, I see the an error. Can someone please help try to get it fixed?

Below are the contents of my sources.list and the error:

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
###############################################################################
# Rackster APT-Mirror
#
deb http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/packages wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/security wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

###############################################################################
# Backupmirror
#
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

###############################################################################
# Backports
#
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib non-free
```

root@vps:~#apt-get update

```
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg
Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-backports Release.gpg
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-backports Release
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy Release
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-backports/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/non-free i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-backports/contrib i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-backports/non-free i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy/non-free i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-backports/contrib Translation-en/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-backports/main Translation-en/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-backports/non-free Translation-en/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy Release.gpg
  Could not connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:80 (213.133.99.97). - connect (110:         Connection timed out)
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:
Ign http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy Release
Ign http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/updates Release
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/contrib i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/non-free i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/contrib Translation-en
  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/non-free Translation-en
  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/updates/contrib i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/updates/non-free i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/updates/contrib Translation-en
  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:
Err http://apt.rackster-server.ch wheezy/updates/non-free Translation-en
  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/packages/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Could not connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:80 (213.133.99.97). - connect (110: Connection timed out)

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/security/dists/wheezy/updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/packages/dists/wheezy/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/packages/dists/wheezy/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/packages/dists/wheezy/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/packages/dists/wheezy/contrib/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/packages/dists/wheezy/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/packages/dists/wheezy/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/security/dists/wheezy/updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/security/dists/wheezy/updates/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/security/dists/wheezy/updates/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/security/dists/wheezy/updates/contrib/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/security/dists/wheezy/updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://apt.rackster-server.ch/debian/security/dists/wheezy/updates/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to apt.rackster-server.ch:http:

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Are you sure rackster-server is still up? It's the only thing that's failing there

Comment: What were you using it for? They might've moved.

Comment: @JMercer... Its a part of the VPS image I got from my provider. Any other source that i could add to the list to validate if all packages can be updated?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming; http://unix.stackexchange.com would be a better fit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like Apt is working and finding the debian repository just fine, however, the rackster server isn't working.

now that the obvious conclusion has been drawn, the tricky bit:

Finding a solution to a problem with rackster's repository is the hard part. Debian's updates will probably keep you secure and functional without the rackster updates but because rackster is a private corporation, I doubt that many people will be able to tell you what their line actually is. You might just have the wrong line so the best course of action is probably to contact customer support and ask them if you got the right line. You may even want to comment out the rackster lines for now so that you can update without being innundated by errors.

Comment: This is probably my first vps. And it turns out that Rackster is not responding with apt. Is there any other repo that I need to add or simply removing the Rackster will be okay? Just apprehensive about my first vps

Comment: I did comment out the rackster's sources, and added official sources. Hopefully now its all set.

Answer (score 3):

As the creator of the Rackster OpenVZ templates I might be able to get things up'n'running.

The templates are mainly built for our own customers, so we reference our own apt repository by default to save bandwidth etc. You can however safely replace the lines with official Debian (Wheezy) repositories as all the packages are vanilla upstream/original Debian.

You still might want to inform your provider so he can "fix" this by changing those lines in his local copies.

And just for completeness, their's a dedicated project page for the template: https://projects.rackster.ch/OpenVZ/Templates/Debian%207/Overview.md

Hope the template does well for you & much pleasure with your VPS.

Regards

Comment: Thanks, I have shared the feedback with my host. Hopefully they incorporate it. If not, well, I understand why is it failing :)